# probability dist'n

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

How many people have to be in the class so that there is a 50% chance of having the same birthday as the instructor?

Answer: I set it up with the rule of complement such that 1 - P(not having same birthday as prof) = 1 - 364/365*...*(365-n+1)/365 and we bound this by 1/2. And, I solve for n. Is this correct?

Comment: A bit hard to parse what you have written, but I don't believe it is correct.  The probability that the first person doesn't match the fixed date  is $\frac {364}{365}$.  The probability that neither of the first two match the fixed date is $\left(\frac {364}{365}\right)^2$ and so on.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Same_birthday_as_you

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. There is no reason for the numerator to be decreasing. It does not matter whether the students share a birthday with each other.

So P(some students share a birthday) = 1-P(all students' birthdays are not instructor's birthday).

P(all students' birthdays are not instructor's birthday)$=\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n$, so you're looking for the smallest $n$ for which $1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n\geq0.5$.

If you simplify, you can log both sides, bring out the $n$ and see that $n\approx\log(0.5)/\log(\frac{364}{365})$.

All of this is a slight simplification because of leap years, but that probably does not effect the calculation enough to change the number of students needed.

Comment: (+1). Alternatively, a brute force 'grid search': In R, `n = 1:366; min(n[1-(364/365)^n >= .5])` returns 253. (`1:366` is the vector of numbers from 1 through 366, and `[ ]` can be read 'such that'.)